Как сохранить размер кнопки неизменным, несмотря на масштабирование в accessibility?
В Jetpack Compose у меня есть кнопка:
Button(
    modifier = Modifier
        .width(350.dp)
        .height(50.dp),
    onClick = { }
) {
    Text(text = "MY TEXT")
}

Проблема в том, что когда пользователь включает настройки accessibility и увеличивает «размер экрана», моя кнопка (как и ожидалось) увеличивается соответственно.

Есть ли способ сохранить размер кнопки неизменным, несмотря на масштабирование accessibility?
UPD
Мой вопрос касается размера кнопки, а не размера текста.

setScaleX/Y не подойдет?
